# Display Array value in php

Tags: php

```
  $_REQUEST['assignment_site_id'];
```

Its output is

```
Array
(
 [47] => 15
 )
```

47 become dynamically. this is changed time to time like

```
  Array
 (
 [34] => 16
 )
```

I want 15 or 16.

How I can get this value.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) would yield the first entry from an array regardless of its index. (If that was your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to print out the value of an associative array entry.

```
foreach ($Array as $key => &$value){
echo "Element $key is $value";
}
```

This would output "Element 47 is 15";

If that is what you are trying to find to do, print out the value of an array entry.

Comment: There's no such thing as `for each`

Comment: I just corrected it as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do. But this will output your expected result.

```
  $yourVar = array();

  $newValue = '';
  foreach($yourVar as $key => $value){
    $newValue = $value['your_searching'];
  }
   print_r($newValue);
```